# Multilingual site: switching languages

Tags: php, multilingual

I’m using a multilanguage script to change from lanquage.
Now I’m having troubles to change from a language when I’m at the default language (English)

The site looks like:

```
example.com ( Main directory)
example.com/fr/
example.com/es/
```

When I’m at example.com/fr/blabla/index and I want to go to example.com/es/blabla/index it works fine.

But when I’m at example.com/blabla/index and I want to go to example.com/fr/blabla/index . I’m redirect to example.com/fr/index

I’m using:

```
<?php
function switchLanguage($lang) {
    $u = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $u[1] = $lang;
    return implode('/', $u);
}

?>
```

So it’s logic that I’m not redirect to the correct path because there is no directory /eng.

I was thinking is it possible to rewrite the url using a array?
Something like this:

```
<?php 
function switchLanguage($lang) 
$array1 = array(' ', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$array2 = array('$lang', ' ');
$newArray = array_combine($array1, $array2);

foreach ($newArray as $key ) {
        echo "$key $value"; 
}

?>
```

But how can I get the value in a url or where Am I going wrong.

To use a database or .ini and geoip caching is not an option

Comment: Could you please explain me one thing: when you go to example.com/fr/blabla/index you're redirect to example.com/fr/index. Then you're saying that "there is no directory /eng". Where does that "eng" come from?

Comment: Is it default language that your script still implodes to the path you want to be redirected to?

Comment: Almost there,  It’s looking promising!

I’ll explain it hopefully now better:

A visitor is on the page: 

    Example.com/sub1/index.php

And he want to change the language to Spanish.
I want that the redirect is to:

    Example.com/es/sub1/index.php

But now he’s (still) going to:

    Example.com/es/ index.php

So the directory sub1 must come after /es/

Answer (score 1):

```
function switchLanguage($lang, $defaultLang = "eng") {
    if($lang == $defaultLang) {
        $lang = "";
    }
    $u = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $u[1] = $lang;
    return implode('/', $u);
}
```

This might work, if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Almost there,  It’s looking promising!

I’ll explain it hopefully now better:

A visitor is on the page: 
Example.com/sub1/index.php

And want to change the language to Spanish.
I want that he is redirect to:

Example.com/es/sub1/index.php

But now he’s (still) going to:
Example.com/es/ index.php

So the directory sub1 must come after /es/

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the first directory by doing `$u[1] = $lang`.  You need to rebuild the array, pushing the language into the right place, not by overwriting something that may already be there (e.g. a directory)

Edit:
Use array_splice to add in the language part:

```
<?php
function switchLanguage($lang) {
    $u = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $u = array_splice($u,1,0,$lang);
    return implode('/', $u);
}

?>
```

Comment: Almost there,  It’s looking promising!

I’ll explain it hopefully now better:

A visitor is on the page: 

    Example.com/sub1/index.php

And he want to change the language to Spanish.
I want that the redirect is to:

    Example.com/es/sub1/index.php

But now he’s (still) going to:

    Example.com/es/ index.php

So the directory sub1 must come after /es/

Comment: I've tested it here www.addressq.com/test.php but it wont't work